# Conversion from Linq Query syntax to Method syntax

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the query shown below. I need to change from LINQ `query syntax` to `method syntax`.

```
(from item in list.OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.amount)
                   where item.active == false select item)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list.Where(x => !x.Active)
    .OrderbyDescending(x => x.id)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.amount)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

There's no point sorting the items if they're not active so the `Where` clause comes first.

As you want the item there's no need for the `Select` statement.